# Jquery list passes values null in controller side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Here i create a tModelList in client side and pass it through ajax call.but in my controller it shows me there's a Count = 1 but all the data's(NewsOrigin / NewsDestination) are null.but in here i pass newsId seperately.. newsId passes successfully,

```
$("#newsline").click(function(){

    var tModelLists = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        debugger;

        var TDetails = {
            NewsOrigin: data[i]['Origin'],
            NewsDestination: data[i]['Dest'],
        };

        tModelLists.push(TDetails);
    }
    console.log(tModelLists); // [Object { NewsOrigin="UK",  NewsDestination="USA",  more...}]
   //When i trype in console tModelLists[0].NewsOrigin it shows me 'UK'



   $.ajax({
       url: $("#AddNewsInformations").val(),
       type: "POST",
       data: { newsId: $(".newsbar").val(),tModelLists: tModelLists },
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (_retnew) {
       }});
});
```

My Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JArray AddNewsInformations(int newsId,List<NewsModel> tModelLists)//in here tModelList shows me the Count=1 but all the values are null.
{
    //some code here
}
```

News Model

```
public class NewsModel
{
    public int newsId {get;set;}
    public string NewsOrigin {get;set;}
    public string NewsDestination {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: You need to stringify the data and use the `contentType" 'json'` option.

Comment: @BonMacalindong yes it's passing null values

Comment: Try adding a `contentType: 'application/json'` in your ajax call.

Comment: @BonMacalindong tried that.not success

Comment: @TechGuy, You also need `data: JSON.stringify({ newsId: $(".newsbar").val(), tModelLists: tModelLists }),`

Comment: Stringify your data as @StephenMuecke said and also include the `contentType: 'application/json'`

Comment: @StephenMuecke and Bon Macalindong , Yeah! it's working with stringify